# Swift 3: Image returns to its original size or transform after rotation

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I have image view the large image inside, as I rotate it using
CGAffineTransform() , it is rescaled to its original transform or size, still can't figure that out yet.

Needed working scenario is:

I want to have an image view scaled to %35 of its original size, then be able to rotate it programmatically without changed its size. How can I achieve that?

EDIT:

Full scenario is, I have Large Imageview (let's call it main) with image view mentioned above (sub) as its subview.

I scale (main) by 0.5 which scales (sub) too, and after that I scale (sub) by 0.35, so when I rotate it is hard to scale every time. that is why I want a way to rotate without scaling again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
t = t.scaledBy(x: 0.35, y: 0.35)//35% of size
//You can change alter this t value any way you want.
t = t.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 4)//Random value, change to your wanted value
//And then just set it
imageView.transform = t
```

EDIT:
This code works. Retested it now. You sure you are using it correctly?
Just ran tested it now.

```
var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
var imageView = UIImageView()

func scaleImage() {
    t = t.scaledBy(x: 0.35, y: 0.35)//35% of size
    imageView.transform = t
}
func rotateImage() {
    t = t.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 4)//Random value, change to your wanted value
    imageView.transform = t
}
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't work as I hoped. problem is by rotating image view is scaled back to its original size. please check my edit description.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I will try it tomorrow at work and let you know. but can you explain what is the difference after the edit?

Comment: Just made a usable example, showing you that t has to be set each time, and showing how to combine the two, without image going to it's original size. My answer changes the transform, without reseting it. That's basically all. You should be able to use this code, within yours, with a tweak or two. Maybe declare t1, and t2 for each image, and transform them as you need to. They shouldn't reset to original size when rotated.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow at work, thanks again for your help, appreciated.